# Is there any way to pass the User Store domain to the backend in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We have a customized secondary user store and we want the JWT that travels to the backend to have the domain of the user store where the user has logged in or obtained a token. Is it possible to do this?

Why idToken and the JWT token pass to the backend are not the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Why idToken and the JWT token pass to the backend are not the same?

` ->  What are the differences you see in JWT access token and ID token?

Comment: I assume Stapler23 is referring to the backend JWT of APIM https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/

Answer (score 1):

Go to the service provider configuration which is used for user login. Then go to `Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration` and check `Use user store domain in local subject identifier`

[image]

Then, try the user login.
Check the `sub` claim value. The userstore name should be appended as a prefix to the subject.

[image]